# Time zone confusion processing javascript generated date in php

Tags: php, javascript, date, time, timezone

I am located in the (PDT) time zone at time Sat May 11 2013 20:58:51 (my time) I generated a date/time using the following code.

```
var date = new Date();
alert(date);
```

This returns the result

```
"Sat May 11 2013 20:58:51 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

If I then post this date to a php script which processes it in the following way:

```
$date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Sat May 11 2013 20:58:51 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));

echo json_encode($date);
```

I get the result

```
"2013-05-12 03:58:51"
```

Not what I expected. I only get the expected time if I get rid of the "GMT-0700 (PDT)" part from my date/time. So I have two questions.

1. Can anyone tell me how to generate a date of this format but with out the "GMT-0700 (PDT)" part in javascript without using string functions/regex?
2. Is my browser giving me the wrong time zone, or is php interpreting the time zone incorrectly. In either case, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript always take your local server timezone, while PHP is converting your date to UTC, so you need to set your server time zone before using strtotime as follow,

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Sat May 11 2013 20:58:51 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
echo json_encode($date);
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.org/HuZub1ih)**

Or if you would like to convert your js date to `UTC` than use,

```
var date = new Date();
var utcdate = date.toUTCString()
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. Your explanation is compelling but the first  code block still returns the unexpected date/time "2013-05-12 03:58:51" when I run it in my browser.

Comment: If you have check my demo link. you can have a better idea.

Comment: yes, the demo link seems to be working but it is producing a different result from when I run the code on my XAMPP server.

Comment: (PDT) a.k.a. Pacific Daylight Time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29785/discussion-between-rikesh-and-ben-pearce)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date  = date('r', strtotime("Sat May 11 2013 20:58:51 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1- `echo date("l F j, Y, H:i s");`

2-

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$postedDate = "Sat May 11 2013 20:36:24 GMT-0700 (PDT)";

$date  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', strtotime($postedDate));

echo json_encode($date);
```